# Wordpress Query to fetch both posts and pages by a custom field/key

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a slider where I will show some contents(featured image and excerpt) pulled from both posts and pages. I want to filter the posts/pages by a custom field called 'slider'!

So if there are some pages and posts with 'slider' custom field only those will appear in the slider. Is it possible in wordpress? If it is then how?

Some guidance will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the class called [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query), has got a detailed explanation in the Codex. Take a look at the `post_type` argument which accepts an array, thus you can give it a `array( 'post', 'page' )` or any other post types that you want to fetch.

Now the meta fetch could be done in two ways, either via the new `meta_query` argument (from 3.1 onwards I believe) or `meta_key` and `meta_value` which are deprecated since 3.1.

Here's a rough example (haven't checked if this works):

```
$sider_posts = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page' ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'slider',
            'value' => 'yes',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
) );

while ( $slider_posts->have_posts() ) {
    $slider_posts->the_posts();

    // output the slide here
}
```

Hope that makes sense. Cheers!

~ K

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But for some reason I am unable to filter the query by a particular custom field. It just bringing up some wrong posts..

Comment: @med, update your question to include some code, let's try and find out what you're doing wrong. Also please state which version of WordPress you're using.